# ¿'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto get devolvió null?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Hola tengo un proyecto en ASP .NET con c#. Tengo el siguiente código en mi webform1 para pasar el valor que escriba el usuario a otro webform y compararlo en una consulta SQL y me lanza el error:

**'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto get(se refiere al get del webform1) devolvió null.**

Código WebForm1:

```
    public string semana
        {
            get
            {
           return sem.Text; //textbox donde el usuario va a escribir el valor
            }
        }


        protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           if (semana!= null)
           {
                Response.Redirect("webform2.aspx?semana=" + semana);
           }
           else {
              Response.Redirect("webform1.aspx");
           }
        }
}
```

Código Webform2 (aquí me lanza el error)

```
int valor = Int32.Parse(PreviousPage.semana);
//aqui esta el valor del webform1 y lo convierto a int




SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ToString());
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tabla where semana="+valor+",con);

 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                gridview1.Visible = true;
                gridviwe1.DataSource = dt;
                gridview1.DataBind();
                con.Close();

            } 
    }
```

Me he basado en estas páginas para pasar el valor del webform al otro:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/af012424-6a31-4273-b9e7-f8ed6b8c233d/pasar-datos-de-un-web-form-a-otro-web-fom-aspnet-con-c?forum=netfxwebes

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Gracias. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estas enviando la variable como parametro en tu url
para obtenerlo en webform2 debes utilizar `Request.QueryString` de la siguiente manera

```
int valor = 0;
int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["semana"], out valor);

//luego utiliza la variable valor
```

suponiendo que la variable semana es de tipo entero, se le va asignar el valor de dicha variable, sino va a quedar en 0.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder ya lo he corregido, pero ahora me dice este error en esa misma linea: System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.' @WFgo

Comment: que valor le estas enviando como semana?

Comment: sera el que el usuario escriba en el textbox sem.Text... o a que te refieres?

Comment: bueno pero si permites ingresar texto o ningun valor va a romper, ahora si estas ingresando un numero falla igual?

Comment: si lo he validado para que solo escriba numero y me envia ese error :C

Comment: prueba con mi edicion, me suena que no le estas enviando el numero, por eso falla. sino deberia castear correctamente a int. ahi actualice para que no falle en caso de que no sea un numero

Comment: Gracias ya no me marco ningun error pero ya no me muestra nada en la tabla,

Comment: crea otra pregunta con respecto a la consulta ya que son dos problemas distintos.

Comment: paso algo muy curioso mi link aparece asi: http://localhost:49236/Proyecto/webf1.aspx?semana=  pero si yo le agrego un numero al link asi: webf1.aspx?semana=48, si me muestra los datos